# Re-position elements in mobile & revert them back in desktop

Tags: jquery, mobile, append

```
var width = $(window).width();
//MOBILE
    if (width < 640) {
         $("#CR1").insertBefore("MOBILEPOSITION");
    }
//TABLET
    else if (width > 640 && width <1024) {
        $("#CR1").insertBefore("ORIGINALPOSITION"); 
    }
//DESKTOP
    else if (width >1024) {
        $("#CR1").insertBefore("ORIGINALPOSITION");
    }
```

Is there anyway I can have the element append back to it's original position when entering desktop view? Right now this way works 100%, but it would be a lot cleaner if I could construct a function that reverts it back on resize.

Also, the structure of my jquery has all the mobile and desktop in their own functions for appends that is called.

Comment: You can't rely on width to determine the device it's being viewed on.  My phone has higher resolution than my monitor.

Comment: This is true, I really need to start doing that- it is something I have not looked into much.

Comment: This site looks pretty useful for just that... http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/  Also, I think you're looking for `$(window).resize()` ;)

Comment: I was using $(window).resize() before, but it didn't work to well for me. I just have a resize on refresh and resoze on reload function. Thanks for the link!